# creating a macro for iterate in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to practise creating macros in Common Lisp by creating a simple `+=` macro and an `iterate` macro. I have managed to create the `+=` macro easily enough and I am using it within my `iterate` macro, which I am having a couple of issues with. When I try to run my macro with for example

```
(iterate i 1 5 1 (print (list 'one i)))
```

(where `i` is the control variable, `1` is the start value, `5` is the end value, and `1` is the increment value). I receive `SETQ: variable X has no value`

```
 (defmacro += (x y)
        (list 'setf x '(+ x y)))


(defmacro iterate (control beginExp endExp incExp &rest body)
    (let ( (end (gensym)) (inc (gensym)))
        `(do ( (,control ,beginExp (+= ,control ,inc)) (,end ,endExp) (,inc ,incExp) )
            ( (> ,control ,end) T)
            ,@ body
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried multiple different things to fix it by messing with the `,` and this error makes me unsure as to whether the problem is with `iterate` or `+=`. From what I can tell `+=` works properly.

Comment: Your `+=` macro is an unhygienic clone of `incf`.   `(incf x delta)` increments the `x` place by `delta`. Unlike your `+=`, however, `incf` will only evaluate `x` once.   Moreover, you have a bug in it; the name of `x` on the right hand side of the `setf` assignment is hard-coded because it's in a quoted list. If we use `(+= a b)`, the code which is generated is `(setf a (quote (+ x y))`. You can check this using `(macroexpand '(+= a b))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Check the `+=` expansion to find the error**

You need to check the expansion:

```
CL-USER 3 > (defmacro += (x y)
              (list 'setf x '(+ x y)))
+=

CL-USER 4 > (macroexpand-1 '(+= a 1))
(SETF A (+ X Y))
T
```

The macro expansion above shows that `x` and `y` are used, which is the error.
We need to evaluate them inside the macro function:

```
CL-USER 5 > (defmacro += (x y)
              (list 'setf x (list '+ x y)))
+=

CL-USER 6 > (macroexpand-1 '(+= a 1))
(SETF A (+ A 1))
T
```

Above looks better. Note btw. that the macro already exists in standard Common Lisp. It is called `incf`.

Note also that you don't need it, because the side-effect is not needed in your `iterate` code. We can just use the `+` function without setting any variable.

**Style**

You might want to adjust a bit more to Lisp style:

- no camelCase -> default reader is case insensitive anyway
- speaking variable names -> improves readability
- documentation string in the macro/function - improves readability
- `GENSYM` takes an argument string -> improves readability of generated code
- no dangling parentheses and no space between parentheses -> makes code more compact
- better and automatic indentation -> improves readability
- the body is marked with `&body` and not with `&rest` -> improves automatic indentation of the macro forms using `iterate`
- `do` does not need the `+=` macro to update the iteration variable, since `do` updates the variable itself -> no side-effects needed, we only need to compute the next value
- generally writing a good macro takes a bit more time than writing a normal function, because we are programming on the meta-level with code generation and there is more to think about and a few basic pitfalls. So, take your time, reread the code, check the expansions, write some documentation, ...

Applied to your code, it now looks like this:

```
(defmacro iterate (variable start end step &body body)
  "Iterates VARIABLE from START to END by STEP.
For each step the BODY gets executed."
  (let ((end-variable  (gensym "END"))
        (step-variable (gensym "STEP")))
    `(do ((,variable ,start (+ ,variable ,step-variable))
          (,end-variable ,end)
          (,step-variable ,step))
         ((> ,variable ,end-variable) t)
       ,@body)))
```

In Lisp the first part - variable, start, end, step - usually is written in a list. See for example `DOTIMES`. This makes it for example possible to make `step` optional and to give it a default value:

```
(defmacro iterate ((variable start end &optional (step 1)) &body body)
  "Iterates VARIABLE from START to END by STEP.
For each step the BODY gets executed."
  (let ((end-variable  (gensym "END"))
        (step-variable (gensym "STEP")))
    `(do ((,variable ,start (+ ,variable ,step-variable))
          (,end-variable ,end)
          (,step-variable ,step))
         ((> ,variable ,end-variable) t)
       ,@body)))
```

Let's see the expansion, formatted for readability. We use the function `macroexpand-1`, which does the macro expansion only one time - not macro expanding the generated code.

```
CL-USER 10 > (macroexpand-1 '(iterate (i 1 10 2)
                               (print i)
                               (print (* i 2))))
(DO ((I 1 (+ I #:STEP2864))
     (#:END2863 10)
     (#:STEP2864 2))
    ((> I #:END2863) T)
  (PRINT I)
  (PRINT (* I 2)))
T
```

You can see that the symbols created by `gensym` are also identifiable by their name.

We can also let Lisp format the generated code, using the function `pprint` and giving a right margin.

```
CL-USER 18 > (let ((*print-right-margin* 40))
               (pprint
                (macroexpand-1
                 '(iterate (i 1 10 2)
                    (print i)
                    (print (* i 2))))))

(DO ((I 1 (+ I #:STEP2905))
     (#:END2904 10)
     (#:STEP2905 2))
    ((> I #:END2904) T)
  (PRINT I)
  (PRINT (* I 2)))
```

Comment: @Rainer_Joswig This is a nice small tutorial for writing macros. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Turns out I had a problem in my += macro and a couple of other places in my iterate macro. This is the final working result. I forgot about the `,` while i was writing the += macro. The other macro declerations where out of order.

```
 (defmacro += (x y)
        `(setf ,x (+ ,x ,y)))


(defmacro iterate2 (control beginExpr endExpr incrExpr &rest bodyExpr)
    (let ((incr(gensym))(end(gensym)) )
        `(do ((,incr ,incrExpr)(,end ,endExpr)(,control ,beginExpr(+= ,control ,incr)))
            ((> ,control ,end) T)
            ,@ bodyExpr
        )
    )

)
```